# How to relate Python threads to POSIX threads in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.6, psutil

Is there a way to relate the Python thread name and thread ID to the POSIX thread ID in Python 3.6?  Any of the following would do:

- Get the POSIX thread ID from a `threading.Thread` object
- Get the Python thread ID from a `psutil._common.pthread` object
- Set the process command-line for the thread (as reported in `/proc/<id>/cmdline`)
- Set some other thread property that shows up in `/proc` from Python
- Something else

I'm on Linux 4.14 and an embedded platform that's stuck with Python 3.6, unfortunately.  I know that Python 3.8 has `threading.Thread.native_id`.  I have control of the Python process source code and have SSH and root on the system - I can do this from either inside or outside the Python process.